# Yarn transitive dependency replacement (not version)

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have these dependencies:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

`D` has a vulnerability and **there's no version out with the fix** (the PR is out there but the repo is dead).

I'd like to do something like:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "D": "myDwithTheFix@1.0.0"
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

If not I have to create my own `myA -> myB -> myC -> myD` ...

If you want to know, `D` is `underscore.string` and [its ReDOS](https://github.com/esamattis/underscore.string/issues/510).

---

EDIT:

I think my question only makes sense if it is combined with some redirection feature from a bundler, like [webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias).

Because if I replace `D` for `myDwithTheFix`, I'd need to replace or redirect also the references from `C` to point to `myDwithTheFix` instead of `D`.

Comment: Did you look at https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/?

Comment: No, that's why I stated the "(no version)". I need to replace a transitive package for another, not change the version.